# Change choices list in child model Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a model that is being inherited by another one and has a field that has choices. Is there any way I can change the choices options, or append a new item to choices on the inherited model level?

app1

```
class ModelA(PolymorphicModel):
    choice1 = "choice1"
    choice2 = "choice2"
    CHOICES = (
        (choice1, "Choice 1"),
        (choice2, "Choice 2"),
    )
    
    method = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOICES)
```

app2

```
from app1.models import ModelA  
class ModelB(ModelA):
    # In this model, I have to exclusively add `choice3` to choices.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the choice constant out side of your class and then use the constant accordingly like :-

```
choice1 = "choice1"
choice2 = "choice2"
CHOICES = (
        (choice1, "Choice 1"),
        (choice2, "Choice 2"),
    )

class ModelA(PolymorphicModel):
    method = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOICES)

class ModelB(ModelA)
    choice3 = "choice3"
    CHOICES + = ((choice3, "Choice 3"),)

    method = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOICES)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the models are actually on different apps. I am just importing the `ModelA` to the app where the `ModelB` is located.

Comment: thats ok ... you can import the constants in the desired app as well.

Comment: I tried this, but when I create a migration, it throws the error that local field name clashes with field of the same name from base class.

Comment: I removed the declaration of the method field on the `ModelB`. It's okay now! Thank you!